# How can I convert a mathematical formula into a logical formula?

Tags: provable-security

I'm using cryptominisat2.9.6 to solve equation set (including more than 160 equations). There are 160 variables in total, which are as follows: $x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{78},x_{79},y_0,y_1,y_2,..,y_{78},y_{79}$.

For example, the first equation is as follows:
$$x_1+x_2+x_4+x_{10}+x_{31}+x_{43}+x_{56}+y_3 \times y_{25} \times y_{46}+y_3 \times y_{46} \times y_{64}+y_3 \times y_{46} \times x_{63}+y_{25} \times y_{46} \times x_{63}+y_{46} \times y_{64} \times x_{63}+y_3 \times y_{64}+y_{46} \times y_{64}+y_{64}*x_{63}+y_{25}+x_{63}=1$$
Every  equation is different.

In every equation, every variable is 0 or 1. ​ So I want to put all the equations into

cryptominisat to solve the 160 variables. ​ But cryptominisat requires a standard input format, either [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or XOR format. ​ I have no idea how to change the equation into the format.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. If it is, you should look at z3, which does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are working in $GF(2)$, every multiplication is equivalent to a AND and addition to a XOR.

> [$GF(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29) also known as $<\mathbb{Z}_2,+,\times>$ is the [Galois Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) (GF) of two elements: $0$ and $1$.
>
> Because $GF(2)$ is a field,
>
> - addition has an identity element ($0$) and an inverse for every element;
> - multiplication has an identity element ($1$) and an inverse for every element but $0$;
> - addition and multiplication are commutative and associative;
> - multiplication is distributive over addition.
>
> One of the most interesting property of $GF(2)$ is its link with the logical functions over booleans. An analogy can therefore be done between the two:
>
> - The field addition ($+$) correspond to the logical XOR operation ($\oplus$), also $\forall x \in GF(2), x + x = 0$.
> - The field multiplication ($\times$) correspond to the logical AND operation ($\land$).
>
> **Remarks:** $0 + 1 = 1$ ($0 \oplus 1 = 1$) and $1 + 1 = 0$ ($1 \oplus 1 = 0$), therefore $x \mapsto x + 1$ is equivalent to the logical NOT. With this in mind, every booleans operations have an equivalent in $GF(2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I know what you mean.in GF(2),"+"is XOR,and "*" is "&".But my question is how to change the left part of eqation to the CNF format.
  An example of CNF is:
  (x1 | -x5 | x4) &
  (-x1 | x5 | x3 | x4) &
  (-x3 | x4).

Comment: I guess [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280844/using-the-distributivity-law-for-propositional-logic) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF) should help.

Comment: But I don't thinks this is the domain of cryptography anymore. Sorry if I can't help you more at the moment, I'm pretty busy. :s

Comment: The issue with xor is treated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897838/translate-n-xor-expressions-to-cnf